# Background css image won't show in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image

http://nategines.com/Beta/HTML/work2.html

I purchased this template online and I added separate background images css images to  and . The idea is that I want two background images that overlap.

The page displays fine in chrome and Safari, but in firefox the background image that is attached to  doesn't display and the image attached to  displays, but ignores the y position.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: which background?? can you point at the proper div tag??

Comment: One background image is attached to <html> (grey lines) and the other is attached to <body> (white circle). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `background-position-y` not works in firefox as it suppsoed to be

So it should be

```
background-position: center 35px;

body{
background: url('../../images/eraser.svg') no-repeat scroll center;
background-size: auto 350px;
background-position: center 35px;
}
```